# How do I show convexity/concavity of $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R} = \arcsin(1 - 2x^2)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

$f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R} = \arcsin(1 - 2x^2)$

I was wondering if there's any other method apart from the second derivative one (which is quite complicated).

Comment: I think the second derivative test is your best bet. Otherwise you could try using graphing software.

Comment: Some care is needed, the function is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Note that the function is even and when restricted to $[0,1]$ it is differentiable with $f'(0) = -2$ and $f''(x) \le 0$ (the latter is messy to show). Combine these facts to conclude that it is concave on the entire domain.

Comment: One hint would be to note $f$ has a strict max at $0.$ That at least tells you what to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative is always negative on the given domain. Indeed we have

$f'(x)=-\dfrac{2 x}{\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}$

and $f''(x)=-\dfrac{2 \sqrt{x^2-x^4}}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}>0,\quad \forall x\in[-1,1]$

Comment: The second derivative is $0$ at $x=0$. The last inequality should be reversed.

Comment: The first and second derivatives are undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider

$$ g:\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right],\qquad g(x)=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin x}{2}}=-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) $$
This function is quite blatantly non-positive, increasing and convex.
By considering its inverse function we have that $f(x)$ is non-negative, decreasing and concave on $[0,1]$. By parity it follows that $f(x)$ is concave on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-(1-2x^2)^2}}=-\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
is odd, if $x\in (-1,0)$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
which is clearly strictly decreasing over $(-1,0]$. Then by simmetry $f$ is concave over $[-1,1]$ and $0$ will be an inflection point for $f$.